# Enlarge DataTemplate Image of Button

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to make the Icon Image within my button Bigger. I was wondering how abouts do I do that.

```
    <Button ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Icons.Home}"  Width="60" Height="40">
    </Button>
```

http://snag.gy/ARTls.jpg

I've changed the Width and height of the Icons.Home within the resource dictionary but that didn't seem to have a driving factor.

Icon Code if it plays a factor

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid>
    <Grid Name="backgroundGrid" Width="256" Height="256" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <Path Data="M10.867,0L15.175004,3.5474122 15.175004,0.66600073 17.616003,0.66600073 17.616003,5.5574448 22.066,9.2217805 18.980004,9.2217805 18.980004,16.776999 12.422999,16.776999 12.422999,11.443829 9.3120081,11.443829 9.3120081,16.776999 2.7570027,16.776999 2.7570027,9.2217805 0,9.2217805z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FF243670" Width="256" Height="256" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
      <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
          <TransformGroup.Children>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
          </TransformGroup.Children>
        </TransformGroup>
      </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
  </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Slap an Image in the content.  Set the size to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer,

If I change the ScaleTransform it'll increase the Icon Image. 
Changed X=2 and Y=2 and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Please use the content property to overdoing the button template like below

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource CommonMainButtonStyle}"
                        Command="{Binding HadaProblemCommand}">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource CommonSubHeaderTextBlockStyle}" Text="Report Problem"/>
                        <Image Grid.Row="1" Height="150" Margin="25" Width="150" Stretch="Uniform" Source="WorksImages/13-002.png"></Image>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
```